# How to use EventLoopFuture in Swift properly?

Tags: swift, promise, future, grpc, swift-nio

I'm new to EventLoop futures and promises. My software stack:

- Backend in Go + gRPC
- iOS client in Swift + SwiftUI + GRPC + NIO

I've got something to work and looking for suggestions on how to improve it since I'm a little lost in docs around `.map`, `.flatMap`, `.always`, etc.

Here's a relevant function from my gRPC data singleton within iOS app:

```
import Foundation
import NIO
import GRPC

class DataRepository {
    static let shared = DataRepository()
    // skip ...

    func readItem(id: Int64, eventLoop: EventLoop) -> EventLoopFuture<V1_ReadResponse> {
        // TODO: Is this the right place?
        defer {
            try? eventLoop.syncShutdownGracefully()
        }

        let promise = eventLoop.makePromise(of: V1_ReadResponse.self)

        var request = V1_ReadRequest()
        request.api = "v1"
        request.id = id

        let call = client.read(request, callOptions: callOptions) // client - GRPCClient initialized in the singleton

        call.response.whenSuccess{ response in
            return promise.succeed(response)
        }

        call.response.whenFailure{ error in
            return(promise.fail(error))
        }

        return promise.futureResult
    }
```

My code in SwiftUI View:

```
import SwiftUI
import NIO

struct MyView : View {
    @State private var itemTitle = "None"

    var body: some View {
        Text(itemTitle)
    }

    func getItem() {
        let eventLoopGroup = MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup(numberOfThreads: 1)
        let result = DataRepository.shared.readItem(id: 1, eventLoop: eventLoopGroup.next())

        _ = result.always { (response: Result<V1_ReadResponse, Error>) in

            let res = try? response.get()                
            if let resExist = res {
                self.itemTitle = resExist.item.title
            }

            _ = response.mapError{ (err: Error) -> Error in
                print("[Error] Connection error or item not found: \(err)")
                return err
            }
        }
    }
```

Should I refactor `getItem` and/or `readItem`? Any specific suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I have one very concrete suggestion, followed by a few general ones. The first, most concrete suggestion is that if you aren't writing NIO code, you probably don't need to create `EventLoop`s at all. grpc-swift will create its own event loops, and you can simply use those for callback management.

This lets you refactor your `readItem` code to simply be:

```swift
func readItem(id: Int64, eventLoop: EventLoop) -> EventLoopFuture<V1_ReadResponse> {
    var request = V1_ReadRequest()
    request.api = "v1"
    request.id = id

    let call = client.read(request, callOptions: callOptions) // client - GRPCClient initialized in the singleton
    return call.response
}
```

This is a great simplification of your code, and lets you defer essentially all of the complicated work of managing event loops to grpc-swift, so you can worry about your application code.

Otherwise, here are a few general suggestions:

#### Don't shut down event loops you don't own

At the top of `readItem` you have this code:

```swift
// TODO: Is this the right place?
defer {
    try? eventLoop.syncShutdownGracefully()
}
```

You can see I deleted it in my example above. That's because this is not the right place for this. Event loops are long-lived objects: they are expensive to construct and shut down, so you want to do that very rarely. In general, you want your event loops to be constructed and owned by a fairly high level object (like an `AppDelegate`, or some high-level view controller or `View`). They will then be "borrowed" by other components in the system. For your specific app, as I've noted, you probably want your event loops to be owned by grpc-swift, and so you shouldn't be shutting down *any* event loops, but in general if you take this policy, then a clear rule applies: if you didn't create the `EventLoop`, don't shut it down. It's not yours, you're just borrowing it.

In fact, in NIO 2.5.0 the NIO team [made it an error](https://github.com/apple/swift-nio/pull/1055) to shut down an event loop in this way: if you replaced `try?` with `try!` you'd be seeing crashes in your application.

#### EventLoopGroups are top-level objects

In your `MyView.getItem` function you create a `MultiThreadedEventLoopGroup`. My advice above is for you to not create your own event loops at all, but if you're going to, this isn't a great place to do so.

For SwiftUI, the best thing to do is to have your `EventLoopGroup` be an `EnvironmentObject` that is injected into the view hierarchy by the `AppDelegate`. Every view that needs an `EventLoopGroup` can then arrange to extract one from the environment, which allows you to share the event loops across all views in your application.

#### Thread safety

`EventLoopGroup`s use a private pool of their own threads to execute callbacks and application work on. In `getItem` you modify the view state from within one of these future callbacks, instead of from the main queue.

You should use `DispatchQueue.main.async { }` to rejoin the main queue before modifying your state. You may want to wrap this in a helper function like this:

```swift
extension EventLoopFuture {
    func always<T>(queue: DispatchQueue, _ body: (Result<T>) -> Void) {
        return self.always { result in
            queue.async { body(result) }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Callback refactoring

As a minor quality of life thing, this block of code could be refactored from:

```swift
let res = try? response.get()                
if let resExist = res {
    self.itemTitle = resExist.item.title
}

_ = response.mapError{ (err: Error) -> Error in
    print("[Error] Connection error or item not found: \(err)")
    return err
}
```

to this:

```swift
switch response {
case .success(let response):
    self.itemTitle = response.item.title
case .failure(let err):
    print("[Error] Connection error or item not found: \(err)")
}
```